# How to proxy an url

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, proxy, javascript, cors

I want to do some local debugging of local javascript files instead of production javascripts.

But I am getting all kinds of CORS blocking , What I need is

if I open something like `randomtargetdomain.com/myscript.js` -- It should show content of `localhost/myscript.js` without redirecting.Kind of like proxy.

Please help with this thank you.